# Return value from function as value for parameter in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, fancybox, fancybox-2

The value of the parameter `content` should be a function which gets the content. I thought I can use something like this:

```
$(".fancy-detail-page").fancybox({
      'content'    : function(){
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          id = id.replace("pd", "c");
          var content = $('#' + id + ' .product-details').html();
          return content;
      },
      'padding'    : 0,
      'openEffect'  : 'none',
      'closeEffect'  : 'none',
      'maxWidth'    : 960
 });
```

But `return` doesn't seem to work. How is this correctly done?

Comment: Would wrapping it in parentheses like (function() { ... return content })() work?

Comment: @testing It should like here: http://jsfiddle.net/s6ZKT/

Comment: @roasted: Your code works. I think it's because it can't get the `id`. So I would have to put in a `click` function I think.

Comment: 'this' refers to window object in your code

Comment: @roasted: I posted my solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to jqueryrocks and roasted. This solution worked for me:

```
  $(".fancy-detail-page").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.fancybox({
      'content'    : (function(){
        id = id.replace("pd", "c");
        var content = $('#' + id + ' .product-details').html();
        return content;
      })(),
      'padding'    : 0,
      'openEffect'  : 'none',
      'closeEffect'  : 'none',
      'maxWidth'    : 960
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Without complicating things too much, you could have used the `beforeLoad` callback to get the same result, and it would have been cleaner, simpler and quicker like :

```
$(".fancy-detail-page").fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    maxWidth: 960,
    beforeLoad : function () {
        var id = $(this.element).attr("id").replace("pd", "c");
        this.content = $('#' + id + ' .product-details').html();
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XDxGt/)**

and this line

```
this.content = $('#' + id + ' .product-details').html();
```

can be reduced to this

```
this.content = $('#' + id + ' .product-details');
```

no need of `.html()` to get the same result ... see
**[updated JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XDxGt/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the same plugin.

Per API looks like 'content' must be data.

"content Forces content (can be any html data)"
http://fancybox.net/api

So you just need to call the function(or set a content var)before initializing fancybox;

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
id = id.replace("pd", "c");
var content = $('#' + id + ' .product-details').html();

$(".fancy-detail-page").fancybox({
      'content'    : content,
      'padding'    : 0,
      'openEffect'  : 'none',
      'closeEffect'  : 'none',
      'maxWidth'    : 960
 });
```

Comment: The problem here is the `id` attribute. Perhaps it will work by defining an own function. I'll try it.